# How to assign a value to a dictionary if I need to reference it in the right hand side?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the code that is giving me a KeyError. I understand why it's doing it but I am blank at how to solve it:

```
mydict = {}

range_val = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(100)]

for v in range_val:
   mydict[v] = mydict[v] + 1  # Should create key if doesnt exist yet and value be 1
                              # Should update key if already exists and update value to +1
```

I get the data from reading a bunch of files and doing some processing to get the information I need. That information is held on another dictionary that I then use to try to do that. That is, instead of `range_val` like in the example I have `somedict.values()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict` was designed for this.

```
import collections
mydict = collections.defaultdict(int)

range_val = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(100)]

for v in range_val:
   mydict[v] = mydict[v] + 1
```

Comment: Hey thank you for replying. I am not getting the following "you created the elements as strings, you can't add an integer to them". I mean, the KEYS are strings, but the VALUES need to be integers since they keep a running count. If I do the "mydict[v] + '1'" isn't that joining for a string?

Comment: you need to use `defaultdict(int)` and then you can use `+1`

Comment: @OsmanMamun But if I do that the keys should be int too? Because the dictionary I get the values from (that are going to be keys for this dictionary) are strings.

Comment: @SJPRO, you're quite right.  I read something into your code that wasn't there.

Comment: @OsmanMamun Solution worked, keeps KEYS as strings and VALUES as integers and adds them. Now, I just googled the workings of defaultdict , if I understand right it will give a default value for keys that do not exist, my last question is: If I write defaultdict(int) will it always assume the default value to be 0?

Comment: @TimRoberts Happens, I sometimes read something into my code that isn't there. Because you both I solved it, thank you very much!

Comment: The default value of the keys is not needed but you're right the implicit default value would be 0 for int and '' for str

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count how many occurrences of each item are in your iterable, you want `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter


my_dict = Counter(range_val)
```

Comment: Later for sure I'll try how this works, but the code is such a mess right now that I am scared to move anything out of place. Thanks!